# Error in MarkLogic Optic Query - to get percentage of occurrence of a record in a template view document

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I am trying to find the percentage of a certain record based on a condition to the total no of that record . I am using optic query to get the result.

To be specific on the requirement :

Give a percentage of a certain record, when there is a condition, with the total number of that record available in the template view.

Here is my optic query which I am trying -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
import module namespace ofn="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/fn" at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-fn.xqy";
import module namespace osql="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/sql" at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-sql.xqy";  
declare option xdmp:mapping "false";
let $view := op:from-view("GTM2_Shipment", "Shipment_View")
let $Ancillary_QuotePrice := op:view-col("Shipment_View", "Ancillary_QuotePrice")
return $view
=> op:group-by((),(op:count("TotcountOfColumn", $Ancillary_QuotePrice),op:count("percentageCount", $Ancillary_QuotePrice)))
=> op:select(
op:as("CountOnCond", op:where(op:and((
                   op:gt($Ancillary_QuotePrice, 0),op:gt(ofn:format-dateTime(op:col('BookingCreateDt'), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]'),osql:dateadd('month',-6, ofn:format-dateTime(fn:current-dateTime(),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')))

                   ))
                   )
      ),
op:as("Percentage",op:divide(op:col("CountOnCond"),op:col("TotcountOfColumn"))) 
             )    
=> op:result()
```

It gives me this error -

```
1.0-ml] XDMP-TOOFEWARGS: (err:XPST0017) op:where(op:and((op:gt($countOfColumn, 0), op:gt(ofn:format-dateTime(op:col("BookingCreateDt"), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]"), osql:dateadd("month", -6, ofn:format-dateTime(fn:current-dateTime(), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]")))))) -- Too few args, expected 2 but got 1
```

Also please check if my query logic is correct or not.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
import module namespace ofn="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/fn" at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-fn.xqy";
import module namespace osql="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/sql" at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-sql.xqy";  
declare option xdmp:mapping "false";
let $view := op:from-view("GTM2_Shipment", "Shipment_View")
let $Var1 := op:view-col("Shipment_View", "Ancillary_QuotePrice")
let $Var2 := op:view-col("Shipment_View", "Shipment_Ref")
return $view

=> op:group-by((),(op:count("Var2", $Var2),op:count("Var1", $Var1)))
=>op:select(op:as("multiply", op:divide(op:col("Var1"), op:col("Var2"))))
=>op:select(op:as("percentageFinal", op:multiply(100, op:col("multiply"))))
=> op:result()
```

Above is the straightforward percentage found for Var1 with total of Var2.
I want the condition of the Var1 to be added in the code. Where can I add the where condition please.

Comment: where is `$countOfColumn` defined? I am working to repro and change the query (you will need to move the `op:where()` outside of the `op:select`) but wasn't sure if `$countOfColumn` was supposed to refer to the `TotalcountOfColumn` or something else. I don't see that variable let in the example.

Comment: @MadsHansen I have added the simple version of the code where I did percentage of Var1 with Var2. What I need is to add a condition for only Var1. And not sure where I can add this to.

Comment: @MadsHansen - I have corrected the above code , The variable countOfColumn  is not there now. Can you please check my query

Answer (score 0):

[`op:where()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/op:where) expect the first parameter to be the `$plan`. Typically, when chaining calls from a plan using `=>` it is set as that first parameter for you, and you are then providing the subsequent parameters starting from the second parameter with what is explicitly set in the function call.

So, when attempting to apply `op:where()` as the expression for `op:as()` to bind to:

```
op:as("CountOnCond", op:where(op:and((
               op:gt($Ancillary_QuotePrice, 0),op:gt(ofn:format-dateTime(op:col('BookingCreateDt'), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]'),osql:dateadd('month',-6, ofn:format-dateTime(fn:current-dateTime(),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')))

               ))
               )
```

the `op:and()` parameter being specified is the one and only parameter being specified, but `op:where()` has two required parameters.

That is why it throws the **XDMP-TOOFEWARGS** error.